# Do we neened Pagefactory.initElements to initialize the driver if I am extending a class where driver is already initialized?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a class where i am initializing the driver and i want to extend it in all the pages and test cases to use the same reference of the driver . Do i need to use pageFactory.initElements in my page class in this case ? if yes - why?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the page object model then yes you do. pageFactory.initElements isn't about initializing the driver, it is to initialize the page object. If you don't use it, then anytime you try to interact with a webElement declared on that page, you will get a null pointer as the webElement hasn't been instantiated.

[See here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageFactory) for more details

Comment: public class UsingGoogleSearchPage {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
       GoogleSearchPage page = PageFactory.initElements(driver, GoogleSearchPage.class);
page.searchFor("Cheese");
    }
} in this example the driver is declared in this class . my requirement is to refer the driver of the parent class. in that case if i extend the class here and use PageFactory.initElements(driver,GoogleSearchPage.class); would it refer the parent class driver ?